# jquery .append html tags syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 $(".filelist").append("<tr><td>Admin</td><td><a href="+fileadd+">"+file.name+"</a></td><td><a href='javascript:deleteFile("+thedata.fileid+","+thedata.fileid+","+thedata.filename+")' id="+thedata.fileid+">Delete</a></td></tr>")
```

I am making a silly mistake with this.. please correct me, I am getting the following error WHEN I CLICK ON THE DELETE LINK.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Comment: can you try `console.log("<tr><td>Admin</td><td><a href="+fileadd+">"+file.name+"</a></td><td><a href='javascript:deleteFile("+thedata.fileid+","+thedata.fileid+","+thedata.filename+")' id="+thedata.fileid+">Delete</a></td></tr>")` before `.append()` is called

Comment: You have to escape the quotation marks that are inside the Javascript function.

Comment: Sort of - the quotes that are there are needed to build the string, but he needs an additional `\"` around the arg values if they're strings (and presumably at least `thedata.filename` is, `thedata.fileid` might be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var href1="javascript:deleteFile('"+thedata.fileid+"','"+thedata.fileid+"','"+thedata.filename+"')";

var $row="<tr><td>Admin</td>";
$row=$row+"<td><a href=\""+fileadd+"\">"+file.name+"</a></td>";
$row=$row+"<td><a href=\""+href1+"\" id=\""+thedata.fileid+"\">Delete</a></td></tr>";


$(".filelist").append($row);
```

Try *Divide and Conquer*  approach, the above way may or may not solve the issue, but it's easier to read & understand, Rather than a long single line, break it to many.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".filelist").append("<tr><td>Admin</td><td><a href="+fileadd+">"+file.name+"</a></td><td><a href='javascript:deleteFile("+thedata.fileid+","+thedata.fileid+","+thedata.filename+")' id="+thedata.fileid+">Delete</a></td></tr>");
```

Use escape quotation `\"` mark or your variables must have already in it and in last close the statement with `;`

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like that:

```
delete_link = $('<a>').text('Delete')
  .data('filedelete',{id: thedata.fileid, name: thedata.filename})
  .click(function(){
     data = $(this).data('filedelete');
     deleteFile(data.fileid,data.fileid,data.filename);
  })

$('<tr>').append(
  $('<td>')
    .attr('href',fileadd)
    .text(file.name)
    .append(delete_link))
.appendTo('.filelist')
```

This way I would avoid mixing HTML and JS/JQuery code in the same file... Ok it's a little longer, but isn't it smarter than the `.append('<foo bar="'+ gibsy +'">')` style? I always forget a char when I use this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

whenever u are passing any string as a argument u have to pass it under quotation mark and that u can achieve using \". n if the passed string is not a string then don't apply quotation mark otherwise u can get incorrect results.

for more clarification view this answer [live example](http://jsbin.com/iqazim/47/edit)